# Example code swift2 to connect with tls and send using certficate

Tags: swift, sockets, ssl, swift2, certificate

Im trying connect using TLS but i dont know what is problem in my code (swift 2) What should be format of certyficate to send? How I can repair this code? or Write new example code to using in future?

```
 class Sock: NSObject {
       var socket: GCDAsyncSocket

          override init()
          {
             self.socket = GCDAsyncSocket()
             super.init()
          }

        func connect()  {
            do
            {
                 self.socket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue())
                 print("try connect")
                 try socket.connectToHost("10.1.1.1", onPort: 5678)
                 while !socket.isConnected
                 {
                   print("polaczono dalej " + String(self.socket.isConnected))

                 }
             print("connect is " + String(self.socket.isConnected))

                         }
            catch let err as NSError
            {
             print("Error " + String(err))
            }
        }

       //override
        func socket(sock: GCDAsyncSocket!, didConnectToHost host: String!, port: UInt16)
        {
          do {
            //read from file
            let myFileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ca", withExtension: "der")!
            let certificateCa = try! String(contentsOfURL: myFileURL, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)

            //decioding certyficate
            print("client: " + functions.getCertificate().fromBase64())
            print("ca: " + certificateCa)
            let certyfikat: CFArray = [certificateCa, functions.getCertificate().fromBase64() ] //cert.stringToNsData(),

            self.socket.synchronouslySetDelegate(self)
```

// in this place i would like to keep connection but after startTLS connection was discount
                self.socket.startTLS([
                    GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMin: NSNumber(int: SSLProtocol.TLSProtocol12.rawValue),
                    GCDAsyncSocketSSLCipherSuites: acceptableCipherSuites,
                    GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust: false,
                    kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust: "X509",
                    kCFURLNameKey: "Proget Software",
                    kCFStreamSSLCertificates: certyfikat,

```
            ])

            print("Did conect is still run TLS: " + String(socket.isConnected))

            let request:String = "test test test"
            let data:NSData = request.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print("Message with is sending: ")
            print(data)
            self.socket.writeData(data, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
          }
          catch let err as NSError
          {
             print("err socket")
             print(String(err))
          }
       }
```